# Odd Ratio and Logistic Regression

Tags: statistics, regression, data-mining

Windy and Play Tennis = 9
Windy and Not Playing Tennis = 8

Not Windy and Play Tennis = 14
Not Windy and Not Playing Tennis = 8

I performed logistic regression in Weka and got odd ratio as 0.3448 for playing tennis.

I am trying to calculate the odd ratio by hand but it didnt result as 0.338.

What is the steps for calculating the odd ratio?

Thanks You

EDIT: Still the result differs from Weka's result.
My data set is below

Windy   Play

TRUE    yes

TRUE    yes

TRUE    yes

TRUE    yes

TRUE    yes

TRUE    yes

TRUE    yes

TRUE    yes

TRUE    yes

FALSE   yes

FALSE   yes

FALSE   yes

FALSE   yes

FALSE   yes

FALSE   yes

FALSE   yes

FALSE   yes

FALSE   yes

FALSE   yes

FALSE   yes

FALSE   yes

FALSE   yes

FALSE   yes

TRUE    no

TRUE    no

TRUE    no

TRUE    no

TRUE    no

TRUE    no

TRUE    no

TRUE    no

FALSE   no

FALSE   no

FALSE   no

FALSE   no

FALSE   no

FALSE   no

FALSE   no

FALSE   no

Comment: I get odds of playing tennis when its windy of 9/8=1.125 and odds of playing tennis when its not windy of 14/8=1.75.  Overall odds are 23/16=1.4375.  Can you tell us how you were trying to do the calculations by hand?

Comment: odds of playing tennis when its windy 9/17 for instance. wasnt that correct?

Comment: or is it 9/23 i am a bit confused

Comment: You are giving the probability of playing tennis which is Play / (Play + Not).  The odds of playing tennis are Play / Not.  Conditioned on being Windy, the odds of playing are 9/8 while the probability of playing is 9/(9+8).  9/17 is the probability of playing tennis given its windy.  9/23 gives the probability that it was windy conditioned that you played tennis.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation but i still dont know why i dont get 0.3448 as my odd ratio for windy and class play. i added my data set. if you have time and effort i would really appreciate that. @SWilliams

Comment: Looked at your data.  I don't see how you're coming up with the numbers you are quoting for the "odds" of playing tennis on a windy day.  Please detail how you are calculating that by hand using counts you are getting from your data.

Comment: Also, note that odds and probability are two different measures.